# Proof details for the first theorem in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

The Proof details for the first theorem in functional analysis
is given in this website:

I have one questions for the proof of lemma 5 given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/155244/102821).

(1) Why this claim hold? from equality $0+0=0$  and continuity of addition in topological vector spaces it follows that there exist neighborhoods of zero $U_1$, $U_2$ such that $U_1+U_2 \subset W$.  Given $W$ is an open set including $0$,  $f^{-1}(W)$ is an open set $(f:X\times X \longrightarrow X)$, how can we find some open set $U_1$, $U_2$ such that $U_1+U_2 \subset W$.

Comment: The fact that $f^{-1}(W)$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ means there are open neighbourhoods $U_1, U_2$ of $0$ with $U_1 \times U_2 \subset f^{-1}(W)$. If $f$ is the addition, that means $U_1 + U_2 \subset W$.

Answer (score 1):

The base of topology of $X\times X$ is a family of sets $\{U_1\times U_2:U_1\mbox{ open in } X,\;U_2\mbox{ open in } X\}$. Since $f^{-1}(W)$ is open in $X\times X$ it contains some element of the base of the topology of $X\times X$. Hence we have open subsets $U_1$, $U_2$ in $X$ such that $U_1\times U_2\subset f^{-1}(W)$. As the consequence $f(U_1,U_2)\subset W$. In that particulat case $f$ is the addition in $X$, so we conclude $U_1+U_2\subset W$.

Comment: Clear reply. I am confused about the product topology. In fact, the product topology is uniquely generated by the base $\{U_1\times U_2:U_1\mbox{ open in } X,\;U_2\mbox{ open in } X\}$

Comment: Yes each base uniquely defines topology containing it.